# Decoding windows phone memory performance analysis report

Tags: visual-studio, performance, windows-phone-7

I ran perfomance analysis for memory and the analysis report it genrated is not entirely clear to me. The warning is "Instances of System.Int32[] account for 80.90% of allocations. Analyze the Heap Summary for new allocations or visuals."

The report shows 14890 Int32 instances taking 73541684 bytes of memory. I dont understand how can 15000 integar values take 70MB of memory. It's a 32 bit integer. What am I missing?

The memory usage for app is more in memory profiling session than CPU profiling session but I assume that's due to some memory consumed by profiling itself.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFoqP.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not saying you have ~15,000 instances of `Int32` but that you have ~15,000 instances of an **array** of `Int32` (i.e. `System.Int32[]`) the largest of which is is 1,536,012 bytes and the average size being 4,909 bytes and that these account for 80.90% of all memory allocations in the analysis.

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I missed that. Now I gotta got figure out who in gods name is creating an array that large.

Comment: No worries :) I'd say any image loading/manipulation would be a good place to start.

Comment: @MrMDavidson: Hi David. I am also finding such issue. I analysed that i am loading a backgound image at runtime from media library. also, i find excessive allocation going for more than 120%. but memory profiling doesnt states that issue. memory consumption is at level near 20 MB. Makes me confusing. any help?